# Conditional grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I have table with these fields:

- amount
- name
- sender_id,
- sender_email

I am trying to group all records by sender_id or sender_email based on following conditions:

1. If for a record sender_id == 0, I try to find other records with the same sender_email but with sender_id > 0.

   1.1 If I find such records (one or many), I group with them.

   1.2 If there is no such records I make a group by sender_email.
2. If sender_id > 0 then I group by sender_id.

Finally I want to list total amounts per sender_id.

Can this be done in plain SQL? 
I tried many ways but with no luck.

Comment: what ways...u should post them

Comment: Tried do INNER JOIN on the same table based on equal sender_email, but eventually got many duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured how to make it:

```
SELECT
src.grp,
sum(src.amount) AS total_amount,
count(*) AS total_count
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
  d1.id,
  d2.`sender_id`,
  IFNULL(d2.`sender_id`,  d1.`sender_email`) AS grp,
  d1.`amount`,
  d1.`sender_email`
  FROM
  donations d1
  LEFT JOIN donations d2 ON d1.`sender_email` = d2.`sender_email`
  AND d2.`sender_id` > 0
  ) src
GROUP BY src.grp
```